# Convert distanceFromLocation to Int

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation, cllocationdistance

I'm sure there is an obvious solution to this issue, but I've been trying different things for a while now and I can't figure it out. Basically I have got the distance between two points, and I am trying to convert it from a Double to an Int (to remove all decimal points), however everything I have tried hasn't worked.

This is my code:

```
let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
let annotationLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitudePassed, longitude: longitudePassed)

var distance = CLLocationDistance(annotationLocation.distanceFromLocation(userLocation))

if distance > 1000 {
    distance = distance / 1000
    rideAnnotation.subtitle = "\(distance) kilometer(s)"
} else {
    rideAnnotation.subtitle = "\(distance) meters"
}
```

I've tried converting to a string then an int, converting to an int with `toInt()` and a few other things, but to no success.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible I'm missing something, but does `let distanceInt = Int(distance)` not do exactly what you want?

Comment: I tried that and it gave me the error - Cannot assign a value of type 'Int' to a value of '(CLLocationDistance)'

Comment: Could you check to make sure you're running a recent version of Xcode? It works fine in 6.4 and 7.0b2, and I'm wondering whether you're using an older version of Swift.

Comment: Just updated to 6.4 actually! So that's definitely not the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Ah! Just restarted Xcode and did a clean and that got rid of the error. Typical! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Wait a mo… assign an Int *to* a CLLocationDistance? That sounds like an unusual error message. I would have expected something like "Cannot find an initializer for type Int that accepts an argument list of type (CLLocationDistance)." I don't mean to be rude, but could you check your code, please?